# How to display an image based on the coulmn value from the database in gridview?

Tags: asp.net

i am using template field to display image based on condition in table field.

i have field name is_selected i used to store 1 or 0 value

if it is 1 then display "~/images/tick.png" image else display "~/images/cross.png" in gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="980">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selected">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("is_selected").ToString())=="1" ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png" %>'   />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have `runat="server"` you cant use eny logic unless you do it in your code behind file. Change it to `img`

```
<img ID="Image4"  src='<%# (Eval("is_selected").ToString()=="1" ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png" %>'   />
```

if you want to do it code behind:

add `OnItemDataBound="GridView2_ItemDataBound"` to `<asp:GridView>`

Add this to codeBehind

```
public void GridView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        NameOfTheObject item = (NameOfTheObject)e.Item.DataItem;


        Image image = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("Image4");
        image.ImageUrl= item.is_selected==1 ? "~/images/tick.png" : "~/images/cross.png";
     }
 }
```

Comment: I did as you said but am getting error as Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string'

Comment: still am getting error as 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'is_selected'. in database "is_selected" is of bit type

Comment: You can try this by making change in SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can do this in database side as well by this query

select case is_selected when 1 then '~/images/tick.png' else '~/images/cross.png' end as selectimg from [table]

try this this will return you image name as a string and you can directly bind it to your GridView.

Comment: You should not do view stuff in the database query... Just saying

Comment: as we all generally binds data to Gridview using Select statement so that we can use case statement in select command to check proper value and then we can pass related value in select query for that. This is just a sample query we can modify that according to our use